# Search a single record using DataView in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, dataview

[image]

I'm doing a custom report using WinForms in C#. StudentID is set as primary key, and when the user inputs the student ID in the search box above, i want to display the student's data in one row only. How do I do it using DataView? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a [row filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview.rowfilter.aspx) to your DataView